# Как разобрать webhook из АMOCRM?

Tags: массивы, json, google-apps-script

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу вытащить данные с отправленного amocrm webhook'ом.

```
function doPost(e) {

Logger.log(e); //вывод: {parameter={leads[status][0][name]=8494, leads[status][0][responsible_user_id]=3869749...}}


Logger.log(e.parameter); // работает и я получаю: {leads[status][0][name]=8494,leads[status][0][responsible_user_id]=3869749...}}

  Logger.log(e.parameter.leads.status.0.name) // хочу получить: 8494, но не выходит
}
```

Подскажите, не могу понять, толи нужно преобразовать что приходит от AMOCRM, толи научиться работать с этой конструкцией.

Пробовал делать:

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // получаю: {"parameter":{"leads[status][0][name]":"8494", "leads[status][0][responsible_user_id]":"3869749"...}}

Logger.log(e.parameter.leads[status][0][name]) // - естественно ошибка.
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока не нашел нормального решения решил следующим образом, преобразовал [] в __ и теперь обращаюсь к ключам в массиве как и хотел.

```
function doPost(e) {

  var tom = JSON.stringify(e.parameter); 
  var str = tom.indexOf("]");

  debug(str);
    while (str > 0 ){
    if (tom.indexOf("[") > 0){ tom = tom.replace("[","_") } 
    if (tom.indexOf("][") > 0){ tom = tom.replace("][","_") } 
    if (tom.indexOf("][") > 0){ tom = tom.replace("][","_") } 
    if (tom.indexOf("]") > 0){ tom = tom.replace("]","_") }
      str = tom.indexOf("[");
    }

  tom = JSON.parse(tom); // получаю: {leads_status_0_name_=8494, leads_status_0_responsible_user_id_=3869749...}}

  debug(tom.leads_status_0_name_); // а здесь получаю: 8494



  bot(tom);
}
```